# pandas unnest on multiple columns(not a list)

Tags: pandas

I have input data like this:

```
    id another_id origin title
0  id1      uuid1     o1    t1
1  id2      uuid2     o2    t2
```

I need be able to specify to 'explode' on `explode_columns=['origin', 'title']`
such that I get something like this

```
    id another_id attribute value
0  id1      uuid1    origin    o1
1  id1      uuid1     title    t1
2  id2      uuid2    origin    o2
3  id2      uuid2     title    t2
```

Comment: The expected output is incorrect, there is no `id2` in the data. Other than that, it is a melt.

Comment: corrected, thanks!